# How do you create a local database in visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am new to visual studio. 
I made an app using excel vba that converts words into code 128 and display them.
I tried to recreate it, with visual studio, but I have no idea how to create a file that store data. 
For example, the barcode code 128 table should be accessible through code to convert a simple text into a barcode view. 
I know so far how to create service based database on sql, add column, and rows, but I need to know how to have (or create) a file with stored data to work with (like in excel, you create a sheet filled with data, and then, you can adress  it using vba)

Comment: Write a method in c# that does an Insert into database to add the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a really good tutorial's on the internet who helps you building a local database on visual studio.

I'll give you a initial steps to build one:

1st: After you create your project, Go to **Project** > **Add New Item** > And Choose **Service-based Database**

2nd: Open your database located on Solution Explorer with the name: **nameyouchoose.mdf**

3rd: It will open a DataSource on the Server Explorer where you can add your tables, records, etc...

Good tutorials:

- [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2019)
- [devu.com](https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-59-creating-a-database-in-visual-studio)